# Why is $? always 0 after system() is called?

Tags: c, linux

I'm testing this tiny program under Linux:

```
// foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = system(argv[1]);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return n;
}
```

No matter what is fed into the command-line, an `echo $?` always prints 0, e.g.:

```
$ ./foo anything
sh: anything: not found
32512
$ echo $?
0
```

My question is: Why doesn't `$?` take the same value as `n`?  I've also tested the program under Win32, and `echo %errorlevel%` gives the same value as `n`.  Thanks!

Comment: And can you only reproduce the behavior when `system()` is involved? (A negative value is being returned, is it not? Is this defined in Linux?)

Comment: I've only seen this behavior with `system()`. If I execute `./anything` followed by `echo $?`, the output would be 127.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you print `n` in octal or hex, you'll discover that the low byte of it is always 0.

If you `return WEXITSTATUS(n);`, your program will exit with the status you are expecting.

Read `man system` and `man wait` carefully, and you'll understand.

Comment: You can also just pass n to exit(); ie. `exit(n);`

Comment: @MarkTurner No, you can't. `return n;` from `main()` will result in `exit(n)` (almost) immediately after `main` returns. And *that* will still result in `$?` being `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Only lower 8 bits of the return value are recognized as the exit status, because the exit status is calculated by `WEXITSTATUS` macro, see [SUSv4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08)